# API POST Endpoint for Inline Pull Request Comments?

Tags: bitbucket, comments, pull-request, bitbucket-api

I’m hoping someone can help me be able to post inline comments on PR’s. In the UI version of Bitbucket, you can post a comment on a specific line, for example, line 6 (see screenshot):

[image: screenshot of UI allowing inline comment]

However, when I try to send a POST request to the API, it won’t do an inline comment. All I can get it to do so far is post the comment at the end, rather than on a specific line, like line 6, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of comment at the end rather than inline]

The POST endpoint I’m using is `(https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo}/pullrequests/6/comments)` and I’m sending the following information in body:

```
{
    "content": {
        "raw": "will this work on one line?"
    },
    "inline": {
        "from": 6,
        "to": 7,
        "path": "style.css"
    }
}
```

No matter what I put in the “from” and “to” it always puts the comment at the end, like in the 2nd screenshot, rather than inline, like it does in the UI (1st screenshot). Does anyone have any suggestions for getting the POST request to do inline comments like the UI version allows?

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation tells you how to use them. You should use either-or. In your example you are trying to write on old file line 6, which will be the value taken, which is at the end of the snippet, where the comment is displayed like you show.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did get it to work; I didn't realize the from was for the old file and the to was for the new file.